# counting the number of interactions a persion_id has based on dates in R, with tidyverse

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse

I am trying to get the number of encounters a patient has based on dates. This is necessary in R and with the tidyverse library. An example of dataset is here:

```
structure(list(person_id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), arrival = c("2020-01-01 08:00:00", 
    "2020-01-01 09:00:00", NA, "2020-01-01 10:00:00", NA, NA), completed = c("2020-01-01 9:00:00", 
    "2020-01-01 11:00:00", NA, "2020-01-01 11:00:00", NA, NA), admitted = c(NA, 
    NA, "2020-01-01 11:00:00", NA, "2020-01-01 11:00:00", "2020-01-09 11:00:00"
    ), discharged = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "2020/01/02 12:00:00", "2020-01-13 12:00:00"
    ), encounter_number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the example of a dataset as an output with the new column I want, shall look like this:

```
structure(list(person_id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), arrival = c("2020-01-01 08:00:00", 
"2020-01-01 09:00:00", NA, "2020-01-01 10:00:00", NA, NA), completed = c("2020-01-01 9:00:00", 
"2020-01-01 11:00:00", NA, "2020-01-01 11:00:00", NA, NA), admitted = c(NA, 
NA, "2020-01-01 11:00:00", NA, "2020-01-01 11:00:00", "2020-01-09 11:00:00"
), discharged = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "2020/01/02 12:00:00", "2020-01-13 12:00:00"
), encounter_number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), person_total_encounter = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Caveats!!

As you can see person with person_id number 2 arrives at AE and completed from AE and then admitted immediately at hospital but with no discharge date yet. But still I give an total encounter adding up to 2, one for AE and one for Inpatient, again even without date of discharge. Moreover, person with person_id 3 is admitted twice on different dates, but this gets a total encounter of up to 2, and then 1 for the last admission. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why is the last row 1 for total_encounter.  Should that be 3

Comment: Hello akrun, thank you for coming back from last interaction we had. Anyway, the last row shpuld be 1 since there is a difference lag time. Also, you helped me with last problem taking the data from a list of list and you gave me the answer using pluck function from purrr. I have struggled to get that since I had some problmes. But you have given me the right answer. And then you have delete it. Can you please put the answer back so that I can thick it as right answer?

Comment: thanks, I undeleted that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one thought. If this is not what you had in mind please let me know.

First, you can put your data into long format, with `event` in one column (for arrive, completed, admitted, discharged), and `date` in a second column. And remove `NA` which do not contribute to results.

Then you can filter on events you wish to count. In this case, I selected completed and admitted.

Next you can `group_by` both `person_id` and `date` (just date without time). The `person_total_encounter` will be the `row_number`, which is just the running count or sequence of events for that `date` and `person_id`.

**Edit**: Added `select` at the beginning since the original dataset described by OP likely has additional columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  select(person_id, encounter_number, arrival, completed, admitted, discharged) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(arrival, completed, admitted, discharged), names_to = "event", values_to = "date") %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  filter(event == "completed" | event == "admitted") %>%
  group_by(person_id, date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  mutate(person_total_encounter = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-c(event, date)) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c("person_id", "encounter_number"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  person_id encounter_number person_total_encounter arrival             completed           admitted            discharged         
      <dbl>            <dbl>                  <int> <chr>               <chr>               <chr>               <chr>              
1         1                1                      1 2020-01-01 08:00:00 2020-01-01 09:00:00 NA                  NA                 
2         2                2                      1 2020-01-01 09:00:00 2020-01-01 11:00:00 NA                  NA                 
3         2                3                      2 NA                  NA                  2020-01-01 11:00:00 NA                 
4         3                4                      1 2020-01-01 10:00:00 2020-01-01 11:00:00 NA                  NA                 
5         3                5                      2 NA                  NA                  2020-01-01 11:00:00 2020-01-02 12:00:00
6         3                6                      1 NA                  NA                  2020-01-09 11:00:00 2020-01-13 12:00:00
```

Comment: so I applied the code you have developed to a bigger data and it does not work. Yet, it does work on a small dataset i have given above. The issue lies in the fact that on bigger dataset drop_na gets me an empty df1. Is there a way to deal with dates and take into account those dates when coming with person_total_encounter?

Comment: This may be because you have other columns and need to `select` first the columns to evaluate beforehand. I edited the answer above with this. If this doesn't work, please edit your question with either `str()` or `head()` of your data set to give me a better idea of what your data looks like.

Comment: Okay. Will try to give you the first row, which is a column name only. And if that does not work, then will re-write the question.